# How to filter and list all objects in s3 folder by a certain size using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to get all the files that are a specified size within a folder of an s3 bucket. How do I go about iterating through the bucket and filtering the files by the specified size? I also want to return the file names of those with the correct size.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = 'my-images')
```

A sample output is

```
 u'Key': u'detail/01018535.jpg',
   u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 23, 0, 48, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   u'Size': 13535,
   u'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'},
  {u'ETag': '"cd65991a1c6f118e8b036208a30028a7"',
   u'Key': u'detail/0119AF2.jpg',
   u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10, 17, 17, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   u'Size': 12984,
   u'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
```

for instance lets say that I would want a search for a size of 12984.
Then it would return the 'Key'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to use boto3, I use this function to find zero byte objects. You can tweak it to your needs by filtering on specific size

```
import boto3

def get_empty_objects(bucket_name, prefixes):
    """
    get list of objects from a given s3 prefix recursively
    """
    results = []
    for prefix in prefixes:
        s3client = boto3.client('s3')
        paginator = s3client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
        paginator_result = paginator.paginate(
            Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
        try:
            for object in paginator_result.search('Contents'):
                if object['Size'] == 0:
                    results.append("s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + object['Key'])
        except Exception as err:
            print(">>> Error processing objects of [s3://" + bucket_name +
                  "/" + prefix + "] - " + str(err))
        print(">>> Returning " + str(len(results)) + " objects for [s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + prefix + "]")
    return results
```

Usage:

```
get_empty_objects("mybucket", ["prefix1/", "prefix2/"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `--query` expression:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-images --query 'Contents[?Size==`12984`].[Key]' --output text
```

I put `[Key]` in square brackets to force each one to appear on a separate line.

This syntax works on a Mac command-line. Windows might need different quote marks.

For tips about using such expressions, see: [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: I know the OP was looking for an exact size, but it's also useful to find files bigger than a certain size e.g: ```--query "Contents[?Size>=`1048576`] | sort_by(@, &Size)"```

Comment: If using BASH the backticks need escaping with back slashes. In PowerShell on Windows I was not able to get the escaping to work correctly (e.g. doubling up the backticks did not help)